# Drupal 7 panel content prints the word 'Array' instead of my field and body content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-panels

I am using Drupal 7 with panels. When I place content into my panel it just prints the word 'Array' out instead of the content. This seems to happen with the fields I created and also the main body content as well. Does anyone know how I can fix this at all? Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `render` to the output to print the HTML.

```
print render($variable);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but apply it to what output in which document? The page.tpl one?

Comment: FIXED - this above information is correct but it needs to be deployed to the panels-pane.tpl.php file. Override this and place into your themes directory.